# Windows file upload manager

Tags: windows, windows-10, data-transfer

Looking to transfer hundreds of files (many GBs) to a SMB network share, through a mapped drive. As you can imagine, Windows Explorer isn't exactly up to the task at times, so something that will queue, resume, and retry in the background is ideal. Especially since the mapped drive relies on an OpenVPN connection that may drop and then re-establish itself.

It should be fairly straightforward to queue up some files and then leave the computer on over-night, allowing the software to upload the queued files.

Note, again, products like FileZilla and WinSCP won't do because they are counting on it being an SFTP/SCP/etc connection, I haven't found one that supports either mapped drives or just SMB.

Comment: With a mapped drive you can use pretty much any program for the task, in the same way you would copy files between two local folders.

Comment: @Alejandro such as...? Believe me, I looked. I can't use anything too verbose like RoboCopy; it needs to have a GUI for friendliness and it needs to automatically do that retrying or skipping (and reporting) upon failure. I thought this would be easy to find and I've been really disappointed. What do you suggest?